# Mongo: avoid duplicate files in gridfs

Tags: python, mongodb, gridfs

There is a way to avoid duplicate files in mongo gridfs?
Or I have to do that via application code (I am using pymongo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MD5 sum is already part of Mongo's gridfs meta-data, so you could simply set a unique index on that column and the server will refuse to store the file. No need to compare on the client side.

Comment: will this work? Since mongo drivers insert into the gridfs file in a stream, how would the driver know the md5 for the whole file until the file is finished inserting? Won't the gridfs metadata already be partially written at that point? Or does an insert write to the chunks collection first, and the metadata collection second? If that's the case, would you get orphaned documents in the chunks collection?

Comment: Sean, it works in the PHP driver as I've recently fixed it. It will first add all the chunks, and then the meta data. If it can't add the meta data then it will remove the chunks again.

Comment: It's the "md5" field on the GridFSFile object.

Comment: Does it work in the python driver? I've just taken a look in the Java driver, and I can't see anything that does what you describe. This seems like really useful behaviour that ought to be standardised across all drivers.

Comment: Sean, I don't know. I suggest you file a bug pointing to this stack overflow thing with my description.

Answer (score 1):

You could use md5 hash and compare new hash with exists before saving file.

Comment: @Denis , I have a question sir